# I am NOT a Taxi or Uber Driver!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Can you solve this riddle?

> I am of Greek descent.
>
> I have four siblings who are also famous.
>
> I was born in the ER.
>
> I may not be big, but I have a big job to do.
>
> I am not fat, but my friends are.
>
> I am not a taxi or Uber driver…
>
> I like juice.

(These clues may sound random, but they will make a lot of sense once the answer is revealed!)

HINT:

> I transport my friends into the lymph.

Comment: My favorite: "I am not fat, but my friends are."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Chylomicron

I am of Greek descent.

> Comes from the Greek χυλός, chylos

I have four siblings who are also famous.

> Chylomicrons are one of 5 lipoproteins, including very low-density lipoprotein, intermediate-density lipoprotein, low-density lipoprotein, high-density lipoprotein

I was born in the ER.

> Chylomicrons are formed in the Endoplasmic Reticulum

I may not be big, but I have a big job to do.

> The second half of the name, micron, means small particle

I am not fat, but my friends are.

> Part of the job of lipoproteins is to transport fat particles

I am not a taxi or Uber driver…

> But it does exist to transport things

I like juice.

> The word Chylomicron comes from the word chylos, meaning juice

Comment: Congratulations! You are correct! Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! :) @AndrewClark

Answer (score 9):

Are you,

> Protein(Protein molecules)

I have four siblings who are also famous.

> Carbs, Fats, Fiber, Salts. Famous combination with protein watched in diets.

I was born in the ER.

> Synthesized in endoplasmic reticulum(ER).

I may not be big, but I have a big job to do.

> Protein molecules are small, but very Important in the body.

I am not fat, but my friends are.

> Protein does not make you fat, but carbs and fat, it's friends do.

I am not a taxi or Uber driver…

> Not sure it's related, but okay. It is not a taxi or Uber Driver

I like juice.

> Guava, avocado, etc juices contain high protein. Could also be protein juices or shakes.

Greek Descent

> Derived from Greek proteios meaning , "the first quality".

Not sure though. Just a try.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect! :) @HimeshNandani

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer is

> A (medical/surgical) needle

As,

I am of Greek descent

> Unconfirmed literature says needles are of Greek origin

Four siblings

> Scissors, prongs, knife,  fork, ?

Born in the ER

> ER- Emergency Room, a kind of ICU, where operations are done

May not be big...

> Usually needles are small...but do the important job of stitching...

Not fat...

> A needle is thin, when compared to its other siblings..

Not a taxi driver...

> It drives the suture...

Juice liking...

> To be provided...

Comment: Good answer! I am afraid it is incorrect though, keep trying! :) @MeaCulpaNay